# Protractor writing a cleaner test cases without using browser.sleep

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Im new to protractor and jasmine and  I use lot of browser.sleep to make my test cases work

```
it('Procedure tab-', function() {

        element(by.linkText('Medical History')).click();
        browser.sleep(500)
        element(by.linkText('Personal History')).click();
        browser.sleep(200)
        element(by.linkText('Procedure')).click();
        browser.sleep(500)
        element(by.css('[data-ng-show="ptab.index  === 1"] > [profile="profile"] > #medicalhistory > .card > [header="header"] > .card-header-bg > .title-header > .row > [ui-sref=".procedure.new"] > [data-ng-hide="important"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(500)
        $('label[for="dis4Appendicitis"]').click();
        browser.sleep(2000)
    })
```

What could be more efficient way to write a test case without using browser.sleep........I have been using sleeps because of slower internet connectivity etc....

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

An efficient way to perform any test is by using [implicit](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) and [explicit](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) waits. Implicit wait can be added in conf.js file so that protractor takes it into consideration at the very beginning of test execution. Here's an example -

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000); //Wait for 10 seconds before failing particular actions/operations
```

And explicit waits can be achieved using [`wait()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) function coupled with [`ExpectedConditions`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions).

> This efficiently replaces `browser.sleep()` method by continuously
>   checking for the expected condition specified.

Here's how to use it -

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elem = element(by.css(LOCATOR));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elem), 10000); //Wait for 10 seconds before failing the step
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Girish this helps......how should i wait for a respose of a api call ......Implicit call will fail as the response is not yet received

Comment: @AmoghAngadi does the api call change anything in your webpage UI? If yes, then explicitly waiting for that element to appear or change can be helpful using various expected conditions available in the link mentioned in answer. If that doesn't resolve your question, kindly update your question with the api call details. Thanks